# Need to partition a list into parts following a specific rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list of lists (the inner lists will be referred to as tuples henceforth, just to avoid confusion) :

```py
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]]
```

and I would like to create another list that contains:

```py
[[[1, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 1], [3, 2]], [[4, 1], [3, 3], [4, 2]], [[5, 1], [4, 3], [5, 2]], [[6, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2]], [[7, 1]]]
```

What basically I am doing is scanning the list of tuples, and putting the tuples into sublists until I hit a tuple that has a *higher first coordinate than the previous tuples* (italics is a correction based on a comment, I had meant this but while writing, missed it). For example the first element is `[1,1]` and the next is `[2,1]`, but since 2>1, the first sublist is `[[1,1]]`. Then again, when we hit `[3,1]`, the second sublist created is `[[2,1],[2,2]]` and so on.

How do I implement this in python? Specifically python 3?

Comment: You have [[4 , 1], [3, 3], [4, 2]] in your "expected result" list, is it just a typo or part of the algorithm?  More sublists like these are also present. If your algorithm should make a new sublist if the first coordinate is higher than the previous one, shouldn't [4, 2] be in a separate sublist.

Comment: @Zunayn its not a typo but rather the algorithm. Read the algorithm again

Comment: @Onyambu In the question it says, "has a higher first coordinate", if it is a part of algorithm, it should rather say, "higher first coordinate" than all the previous tuples.

Comment: @Zunayn check the solution I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution assumes that the input data is never an empty list:

```
d  = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]]

d2 = [[d[0]]]
for t in d[1:]:
  if t[0] > d2[-1][0][0]:
    d2.append([t])
  else:
    d2[-1].append(t)

print(d2)
```

The following accommodates the case where the input data is an empty list:

```
d2 = []
for t in d:
  if (not d2) or (t[0] > d2[-1][0][0]):
    d2.append([t])
  else:
    d2[-1].append(t)
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit to allow for the case where `d` is empty.

Comment: Thanks @alaniwi, have edited the solution to accommodate the case where the input data is an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1], [4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1]]

def cummax(v):
    x = v[:1]
    for i in v:
       x.append(x[-1] if x[-1] > i else i)
    return x

d = {} 
for i,j in zip(cummax([i for i,j in a]), a):
    if not d.get(i):
        d[i]=[]
    d[i].append(j)
list(d.values())

[[[1, 1]], [[2, 1], [2, 2]], [[3, 1], [3, 2]], [[4, 1], [3, 3], [4, 2]], [[5, 1], [4, 3], [5, 2]], [[6, 1], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2]], [[7, 1]]]
```